# initializer for conditional binding

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I'm getting an error where I'm combining and assignment along with checking the result of the computation. Please advise

```
var database: OpaquePointer?
if let result = sqlite3_open(file.path, &database), result == SQLITE_OK {

}
```

**Error**: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not `Int32'

I've tried `where result == SQLITE_OK` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to combine both an assignment and conditional check into a single `if` or `guard` statement, then you can use `if case let`:

```
var database: OpaquePointer?
if case let result = sqlite3_open(file.path, &database),
   result == SQLITE_OK {
    print(result)
}
```

... or `guard case let`:

```
var database: OpaquePointer?
guard case let result = sqlite3_open(file.path, &database),
      result == SQLITE_OK else {
    return
}

print(result)
```

Whether this is more or less readable than just defining `result` before the `if`/`guard` statement is debatable, though.

Comment: if case works for me in this case, I wish guard statement would allow access to result within the else clause

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_open(file.path, &database)` is not *Optional*, so you can't use it in an `if-let` statement.

Instead you can do:

```
let result = sqlite3_open(file.path, &database)
if result == SQLITE_OK {

}
```

or

```
if sqlite3_open(file.path, &database) == SQLITE_OK {

}
```

If you want to do this using `guard`:

```
let result = sqlite3_open(file.path, &database)
guard result == SQLITE_OK else {
    // error
    print(result)
    return // `guard` must not fall-through
}
// ok
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to declare/initialize within if statement and then read result for the error no, there will be so many nested sql statements, create inserts etc. so it will be a pyramid of doom, for instance solution with a guard?

Comment: @AppDeveloper To avoid *pyramids* of nested if-s you can use `guard` or `guard-let` statements. See https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/

Comment: @AppDeveloper No, not only, you can do `guard true != false else { return }` where you don't have optionals. See this as well: http://ios-tutorial.com/what-is-the-difference-between-guard-and-if/

Comment: can you please help the above code using guard statement

Comment: thanks, now can I have the result value that i can use within the condition, let's say result is not SQLITE_OK , so I want to check what was the result?

Comment: oh, I see, that's where I was going, I couldn't combine all the assignment and result checking into one guard statement.

Comment: @AppDeveloper I updated my answer. But please read the links I gave you.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your answer, it's a bummer for me that I can't combine both assignment and check into single guard statement.